# Spring Elements not showing under Eclipse Navigator

Tags: spring, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, spring-environment

Although i have enabled Spring Elements and i can see that when i right click on my project, it doesn't show up under my project in Navigator.
I installed the necessary plugins also but still cant figure out the issue.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Spring tool 4. they have **removed** it. they are suggesting for go to symbol which can be achieved by Ctrl+6. But not that much helpful as Spring elements hierarchy.

How to use Ctrl+6 efficiently:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Navigation

Reference to my statement:
https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues/23

Answer (score 0):

The *Navigator* view directly shows the files and folders without virtual nodes. Use the [***Project Explorer* view**](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-27.htm) instead.